# How to shift vertices of shapes in shapefile using FOSS python library?

Tags: python, shapefile, open-source-gis, ogr, shapely

I need to shift each vertice of shape in a shapefile (of any type:point, line, polygon, multiline etc.) with Python. I need to loop in all shapes, get the vertices, get it's coordinates and for each X,Y update with new values. Which Free and Open Source Software (FOSS) library should I use (ogr, fiona shapely etc.)? Any example?

Comment: do you want to move all the points by a fixed offset or does it vary by point?

Comment: It varies by point.

Comment: Did you see this? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21256/how-to-easily-shift-all-features-in-a-vector-dataset

Comment: Yes, but in my case the shift is different for each vertex.

Comment: Then adapt any of those examples to the case of spatially varying shift. Maybe update your question to show how the shift varies?